# Drag and drop Android Java - Keep original view when dropping

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-view

I'm trying to implement a custom Drag and Drop for my Android app (kind of a simplified Blockly approach). The thing is that I have a set of actions availables, on the left, and I want to drag them on the right side, representing the succession of actions.
The drag and drop process works fine, however I'm stuck with one last thing. I would like the original block to keep in its original view. But for now, it disappears when the drop is completed.

Here are some illustrations of my app:
[Drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMkm5.jpg) - [Drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVUtS.jpg)

Here is my code so far:

```
@Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // Determines if this View can accept the dragged data
                if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                v.invalidate();
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                // Ignore the event
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                v.invalidate();
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Gets the item containing the dragged data
                ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                // Gets the text data from the item.
                String dragData = item.getText().toString();

                switch (dragData){
                    case ("Aller au POI"):
                        // SOME CODE
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                v.invalidate();

                View vw = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) vw.getParent();

                owner.removeView(vw); // I would like not to remove that
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                container.addView(vw);
                vw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                v.invalidate();
                if (event.getResult())
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "The drop was handled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout_dragged_mission_blocks), "Action ajoutée", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                else
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "The drop didn't work.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout_dragged_mission_blocks), "Erreur à l'ajout de l'action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setBackgroundTint(Color.RED)
                            .show();
                // returns true; the value is ignored.
                return true;
            // An unknown action type was received.
            default:
                Log.e("DragDrop Example", "Unknown action type received by OnDragListener.");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I understand that `owner.removeView(vw);` may be the problem, but when I remove this line, I get an error :

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Am I doing something wrong?

### EDIT

Here is some additional code:

**onLongClick():**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Create a new ClipData.Item from the ImageView object's tag
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v.getTag());
        // Create a new ClipData using the tag as a label, the plain text MIME type, and
        // the already-created item. This will create a new ClipDescription object within the
        // ClipData, and set its MIME type entry to "text/plain"
        String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
        ClipData data = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
        // Instantiates the drag shadow builder.
        View.DragShadowBuilder dragshadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        // Starts the drag
        v.startDragAndDrop(data        // data to be dragged
                , dragshadow   // drag shadow builder
                , v           // local data about the drag and drop operation
                , 0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
        );
        return true;
    }
```

**onCreate():**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mission_creation);

        // SLAMWARE agent
        mAgent = getSlamwareAgent();

        // Toolbar
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Génération de mission");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Back from toolbar button pressed");
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Blockly-like Drag'n'drop
        //Find all views and set Tag to all draggable views
        goToPOI_block_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.go_to_POI_block);
        goToPOI_block_tv.setTag(goToPOI_block_tv.getText().toString());
        goToPOI_block_tv.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        wait_duration_block_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wait_duration_block);
        wait_duration_block_tv.setTag(wait_duration_block_tv.getText().toString());
        wait_duration_block_tv.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        wait_action_block_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wait_action_block);
        wait_action_block_tv.setTag(wait_action_block_tv.getText().toString());
        wait_action_block_tv.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        say_block_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.say_block);
        say_block_tv.setTag(say_block_tv.getText().toString());
        say_block_tv.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        go_home_block_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.go_home_block);
        go_home_block_tv.setTag(go_home_block_tv.getText().toString());
        go_home_block_tv.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        //Set Drag Event Listeners for defined layouts
        // TODO gérer le cas où on remet le block dans la palette d'actions
        findViewById(R.id.layout_available_mission_blocks).setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
                                                                                 @Override
                                                                                 public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                                                                                     // Log.d(TAG, "Entering onDragListener");
                                                                                     switch (event.getAction()) {
                                                                                         case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                                                                                             return true;
                                                                                         case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                                                                                             ClipData clipData = event.getClipData();
                                                                                             //...
                                                                                             return false;
                                                                                         default:
                                                                                             return false;
                                                                                     }
                                                                                 }
                                                                             });
        findViewById(R.id.layout_dragged_mission_blocks).setOnDragListener(this);
        save_mission_b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_mission_fab);

        actionsToExportLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout_dragged_mission_blocks);

        saveMission();
    }
```

**Layout XML**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MissionCreationActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".BlocklyActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-2dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_available_mission_blocks"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                        android:id="@+id/go_to_POI_block"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:chipIcon="@drawable/pin_icon"
                        android:text="Aller au POI"
                        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/transparent_red"
                        />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"/>

                    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                        android:id="@+id/wait_duration_block"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:chipIcon="@drawable/wait_icon"
                        android:text="Attendre (durée)"
                        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/transparent_green"
                        />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"/>

                    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                        android:id="@+id/wait_action_block"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:chipIcon="@drawable/wait_action_icon"
                        android:text="Attendre (action)"
                        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/transparent_blue"
                        />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"/>

                    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                        android:id="@+id/go_home_block"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:chipIcon="@drawable/home_icon"
                        android:text="Retour en base"
                        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/transparent_violet"
                        />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"/>

                    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                        android:id="@+id/say_block"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:chipIcon="@drawable/say_icon"
                        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/transparent_yellow"
                        android:text="Dire"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_dragged_mission_blocks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".70"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/save_mission_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:text="Sauvegarder la mission"
            app:icon="@drawable/check_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: How are you inflating the layout? Can we see the onCreateView method?

Comment: @Sarah I edited my OP with the code